# Custom Annotation for a block in java

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, annotations

I need to create a custom annotation for a block of code. For example:

```
@someannotation(somevariable="INEEDANSWERS")
{
...
}
```

I have been studying about different target types but none has been able to do this for me. Here is a little background (in case there is an alternative). I want to provide users an elementary framework where in their test methods, they can mark some lines of code as audited/clocked. I have successfully created the complete method as timed but I need further drilled down data. I do not want to provide two final methods (before and after steps). I can also do with bean creation for this but I prefer annotations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This clearly denies the possibility of annotation usage for the purpose. But does not define any other possible solution to it. I have asked for anything possible which does not include startmethod() and endmethod().

Comment: Perhaps because there is no solution using your current requirements. You will have to compromise.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there is no way of controlling the access of running class without using explicit method calls? What about callables. I have not read the complete documentation but I know this thing is feasible.

Comment: What do you mean by "access of running class"?

Comment: By this I mean, I cannot send the control to some generic methods.